# need to link the snippet to a url

Tags: html, css

Please I need your assistance to link the toggle to 2 separate links.. example..1 is [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) and second is [www.ask.com](http://www.ask.com)

I need the 2 links linked to any of the ends of the switch so when it is selected , the switch moves to the selected end and also opens a new windows relating to the link above

```css
.flipswitch {
  position: relative;
  width: 195px;
  -webkit-user-select:none;
  -moz-user-select:none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}
.flipswitch input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}
.flipswitch-label {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid #999999;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
.flipswitch-inner {
  width: 200%;
  margin-left: -100%;
  -webkit-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
  -moz-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
  -ms-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
  -o-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
  transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}
.flipswitch-inner:before, .flipswitch-inner:after {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 34px;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 34px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.flipswitch-inner:before {
  content: "ask  view";
  padding-left: 13px;
  background-color: #256799;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.flipswitch-inner:after {
  content: "google  View";
  padding-right: 13px;
  background-color: #EBEBEB;
  color: #888888;
  text-align: right;
}
.flipswitch-switch {
  width: 31px;
  margin: 1.5px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 2px solid #999999;
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 160px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}
.flipswitch-cb:checked + .flipswitch-label .flipswitch-inner {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.flipswitch-cb:checked + .flipswitch-label .flipswitch-switch {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="flipswitch">
    <input type="checkbox" checked="" id="fs" class="flipswitch-cb" name="flipswitch">
    <label for="fs" class="flipswitch-label">
        <div class="flipswitch-inner"> </div>
                    
        <div class="flipswitch-switch"></div>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the JavaScript? You cannot open a new window without it

Comment: Thank you... that is where i need your help.. for the present, ignore the new window..let it open on same window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this

```js
document.getElementById("fs").addEventListener("change",function() {
  const loc = this.checked ? "https://www.google.com" : "https://ask.com/";
  console.log(loc)
  // window.open(loc,"_blank"); // only works if browser allows it
  location = loc; // will work in all cases where the target allows it 
})
```

```css
.flipswitch {
  position: relative;
  width: 195px;
  -webkit-user-select:none;
  -moz-user-select:none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}
.flipswitch input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}
.flipswitch-label {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid #999999;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
.flipswitch-inner {
  width: 200%;
  margin-left: -100%;
  -webkit-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
  -moz-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
  -ms-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
  -o-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
  transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}
.flipswitch-inner:before, .flipswitch-inner:after {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 34px;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 34px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.flipswitch-inner:before {
  content: "ask  view";
  padding-left: 13px;
  background-color: #256799;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.flipswitch-inner:after {
  content: "google  View";
  padding-right: 13px;
  background-color: #EBEBEB;
  color: #888888;
  text-align: right;
}
.flipswitch-switch {
  width: 31px;
  margin: 1.5px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 2px solid #999999;
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 160px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}
.flipswitch-cb:checked + .flipswitch-label .flipswitch-inner {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.flipswitch-cb:checked + .flipswitch-label .flipswitch-switch {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="flipswitch">
    <input type="checkbox" checked="" id="fs" class="flipswitch-cb" name="flipswitch">
    <label for="fs" class="flipswitch-label">
        <div class="flipswitch-inner"> </div>
        <div class="flipswitch-switch"></div>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: that's great,.. what of i want it on same page.... no new window

Comment: `location=loc` instead

Comment: If the site does not like to be framed, you cannot use it in a frame like here in SO. 
Location should work in all others cases - window open only if the page is not sandboxed or the user blocks pop-ups